# Dockerizing existing zend web app project

Tags: php, mysql, docker, zend-framework

I have a web based application using Zend framework running on LAMPP server and MYSQL which I would like to Dockerize. Essentially, I would like to do the following:

- Create a docker file that would be my docker container for the web application
- Be able to pass in a configuration to this docker file so that I can build the docker image either for my local code base or pull from master branch

Any suggestions on how do I get started?

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a general best practice you should only have one service - daemon - in each container. So in your case, when you have apache and mysql, you should think about two containers. For running them at the same time you can either put together a simple bash script, or have a look at docker-compose.

The Dockerfile for the apache container would either have a volume mapped to your "live" code on your disk, or it would contain the code inside. To do the former, you would use the VOLUME declaration in the Dockerfile, and then "-v" parameter when running it (or "volumes" declaration in docker-compose.yml). To do the latter, you would use the ADD instruction in Dockerfile.

Now if you want some kind of switch between these two, I would suggest creating three Dockerfiles, such as Dockerfile.parent, Dockerfile.app, Dockerfile.live - where:

- the parent contains all your dependencies
- the other two use "FROM parent"
- app uses the ADD instruction and therefore contains the code inside
- live uses the volume